# ORA error being displayed in Oracle web-app

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've got a error with my Oracle Web App.
When I type the URL "http://mydomain.com/pls/docs" in my browser, I get this error:

> Estado de Descarga
>
> Descarga del archivo falló. ORA-01403: no data found. ORA-01403: no data found

And the code that generates this error is:

```
PROCEDURE LEP_DESCARGA_ARCHIVO IS

      lv_FilePath VARCHAR2(32000);
      lv_FileName VARCHAR2(32000);
  BEGIN

lv_FilePath := SUBSTR(owa_util.get_cgi_env('PATH_INFO'),2);


     SELECT name INTO lv_FileName
     FROM table_file
     WHERE UPPER(name) like UPPER(lv_FilePath);
     wpg_docload.download_file(lv_FileName);

EXCEPTION

  WHEN OTHERS THEN

    HTP.htmlopen;
    HTP.headopen;
    HTP.title('Archivo Descargado');
    HTP.headclose;
    HTP.bodyopen;
    HTP.header(1, 'Estado de Descarga');
    HTP.print('Descarga del archivo ' || lv_filePath || ' fall&oacute;.');
    HTP.print(SQLERRM);
    HTP.bodyclose;
    HTP.htmlclose;
END LEP_DESCARGA_ARCHIVO;
```

The problem is that Error shows too much information in the Error. **LEP_DESCARGA_ARCHIVO** is important for another process in my site.

Where do I have to configure Oracle in order for this Error not to appear? I mean I do not want to get this Error if I type the URL:

```
https://mydomain.com/pls/docs/servlets/index.html
**Error:** Descarga del archivo servlets/index.html falló. ORA-01403: no data found

h t t p s : / / m y d o m a i n . c o m / p l s / d o c s /
**Error:** Descarga del archivo falló. ORA-01403: no data found                        

h t t p s : / / m y d o m a i n . c o m / p l s /d o c s / s e r v l e t s/
**Error:** Descarga del archivo servlets/ falló. ORA-01403: no data found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're displaying this error for two reasons.

Firstly, this query returns no data:

```
SELECT name INTO lv_FileName
  FROM table_file
 WHERE UPPER(name) like UPPER(lv_FilePath);
```

This is why the exception is raised. There is no `name` in the table `TABLE_FILE` that matches your variable `lv_filename`. Whether you want to fix this error is up to you.

The second reason the error is displayed is because of this line:

```
HTP.print(SQLERRM);
```

You're *outputting* it. If you don't want to output the error, you don't have to.

It might be more normal to catch this error explicitly and do something with it, if you want to.

```
begin
   ...
   select name into ...
   ...

exception 
   when no_data_found then
      -- do something
   when others then
      -- do something else
end;
```

Comment: Another technique for avoiding the error is to "select max(name) name, count(*) value_found from ...", and in the absence of a group by a single row is always returned. The value of "value_found" can be checked to see if a value was ... erm ... found.

Comment: Thanks so Much, Mr. Ben, but Do you know Why if i typed the last URLs, these show that error?? i mean, i am not calling the LEP_DESCARGA_ARCHIVO PROC directly. That is my problem i would not like those URLs are active, that is why i want to know where in oracle i can configure these pages are inactive. thanks so much again for your early answer.

Comment: ok estimados gracias por sus aportes!!! Well done guys, thanks for your comments, these help me too much.

Comment: de nada @user2494708, pero Ingles es el único idioma de Stack Overflow. Solamente en Ingles por favor. I'm sorry but I haven't been able to answer your comment. I'm not sure, to be honest. I've never used Apex, I just understand _why_ you're getting the error... not why you're getting it for other pages. It must, as you say, be something in your settings.

Comment: @wtoledo2013 so where are you calling this procedure? Is /pls/docs/ your apex url? Is this apex or is this another oracle web technology?